# Can we arrange an uncoutable amount of points on $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ so that their closure has dimension 0?

Tags: general-topology

Just out of curiosity, can this be done? For the euclidian topology.

Comment: Under what sense of dimension? The Cantor set $K \subset [0, 1] \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ is closed and not really 1-dimensional.

Comment: thank you @Michael, didn't find that question, that was what I was looking for!

Comment: @J.Dionisio : Thanks for the feedback. Apparently someone with the power to do so deleted my comment that identified the prior question, then, the link I gave was included above as if I never existed!